# Reorder a string in R using splitstring

Tags: r, text, strsplit

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to reorder a string, and the easiest way that I could think of doing so was by removing elements and then putting them back in using **paste**. But I can't figure out how to remove elements. Here's a string:

```
x <- "the.cow.goes.moo"
```

But when I use

```
x <- strsplit(x, '[.]')
```

resulting in the list "the" "cow" "goes" "moo".
And try to remove the second element using either

```
x <- x[-2]
```

or

```
[x <- x[x != "cow"]
```

I get the exact same list. **But** when I declare x as

```
x <- list("the", "cow", "goes", "moo")
```

then

```
x <- x[-2]
```

works!

What's different? What am I doing wrong? Also, is there an easier way to reorder a string?

EDIT: I just realized that what I need is "moo.goes.the.cow", but I need to repeat this same change for a number of other strings. So I need to reorder the elements, and can't actually delete them. How can I do that?

Comment: `paste(strsplit(x, '.', fixed=T)[[1]][c(4,3,1,2)], collapse='.')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strsplit` returns a `list` object. So each element of the vector `x` will now be broken out into individuals pieces in a `list`. Lists can be painful to subset in this fashion but it's good to get your head around it early.

In your example, it would be:

```
x[[1]][-2]
```

For your update, you can reorder like so:

```
x[[1]][c(2,1,3,4)] # or whatever order you want.
x[[1]][sample(1:x[[1]],length(x[[1]]))] # randomly even
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! What does the `[[1]]` signify?

Comment: It's the first element of the list. It uses slightly different notation than a vector. The second element of a list, you guessed it `[[2]]`. A named list? `[["list_element_name"]]`

Comment: So a list is basically a vector of vectors?

Comment: yes, or anything else for that matter (data.frames, other lists, vectors).

Comment: Got it! Thank you again, this makes a lot more sense - as a side note, how might I actually permute the order of the elements of a list? I realized that what I initially thought would work... doesn't. I'm really sorry about that!

Comment: Next time if you have a separate question, feel free to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
x<-unlist(x)
x <- x[-2]
```